# Cannot find function addToFolder in Apps Script Code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Am getting an error for the following code

Error Details :Cannot find function addToFolder

```
function createDocument(sourceId, name) {
    var source = DocsList.getFileById(sourceId);
    var newFile = source.makeCopy(name);
    var targetFolder = DocsList.getFolderById(TARGET_FOLDER);
    newFile.addToFolder(targetFolder);
    return DocumentApp.openById(newFile.getId());
}
```

I try to change this code to drive app but it  does not  work until now.

```
   var fileName= theForm.myFile;  
   var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FOLDER_ID);    
   var file = DriveApp.createFile(fileName);    
   file.addToFolder(folder);
```

Comment: You can't use the `createFile()` method with DriveApp with no content being added to the file.  Using just the file name won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
function createNewFileThenMoveToFolder() {
  var theFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('The Folder ID');
  var theFile = DriveApp.createFile('AAAA1111', 'some dummy content');
  //theFile.makeCopy(theFolder);

  theFolder.addFile(theFile);
};
```

The commented out line works also, but you'll end up with two copies.